# Is the second "that" used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, redundancy

> He replied that she no longer knew who he was, *that* she had not been able to recognize him for 5 years now.

Is the second that used correctly here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second *that* is fine since it furthar adds something to *replied that*. Here are a few similar examples;

1. It had first been *suggested that* he be skinned alive, *that* lead be poured into his entrails and that he be let to starve.
2. If you *know that* something unpleasant will happen, *that* you will go to the dentist for example, or to France, then that is not good.

Answer (score 0):

The second "that" is required by [parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)). It means that "He replied" is common to the two clauses, and the meaning must be clear and correct when splitting the clauses, without any other transformations.

> *He replied* **that** she no longer knew who he was.
>
> *He replied* **that** she had not been able to recognize him for 5 years now.

However, if the second "then" is missing, the second clause becomes after splitting:

> *He replied* she had not been able to recognize him for 5 years now.

which is incomplete.